# Encrypting file in Node via Crypto and Stream

Tags: node.js, encryption, stream, fs

I want to read from a stream then encrypt it and finally write it to another file.
This is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var infile = fs.createReadStream('a.dmg');
var outfile = fs.createWriteStream('b.dmg');
var encrypt = crypto.createCipher('aes192', 'behdad');
var size = fs.statSync('a.dmg').size;
console.log(size);
infile.on('data',function(data) {
    var percentage = parseInt(infile.bytesRead) / parseInt(size);
    console.log(percentage * 100);
    var encrypted = encrypt.read(data);
    console.log(encrypted);
    if(encrypted){
        console.log(encrypted);
        outfile.write(encrypted);
    }


});
infile.on('close', function() {
    encrypt.end();
     outfile.close();

});
```

But it returns an empty file, and `encrypted` is null. What is the problem? I don't want to use `pipe` .

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `pipe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to use `Cipher#update` and `Cipher#final` instead of `Stream#read`, because the function signature is `read([size])` and `data` is not a size.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var infile = fs.createReadStream('a.dmg');
var outfile = fs.createWriteStream('b.dmg');
var encrypt = crypto.createCipher('aes192', 'behdad');
var size = fs.statSync('a.dmg').size;
console.log(size);
infile.on('data',function(data) {
    var percentage = parseInt(infile.bytesRead) / parseInt(size);
    console.log(percentage * 100);
    var encrypted = encrypt.update(data);
    console.log(encrypted);
    if(encrypted){
        console.log(encrypted);
        outfile.write(encrypted);
    }
});
infile.on('close', function() {
    outfile.write(encrypt.final());
    outfile.close();

});
```

Since `crypto.createCipher` is deprecated now. You should use `crypto.createCipheriv` where you provide a key and IV. That means that you should stretch the password that you use with PBKDF2 or similar to get a key and generate a random IV to get semantic security. Since the salt for PBKDF2 and the IV are not supposed to be secret, they can be written in front of the ciphertext. Since they have always the same length (salt is usually 8-16 bytes and IV always 16 bytes for AES-CBC), you know how many bytes you have to read in order to get those values back. Keep in mind that the decryption code has to have proper error handling.

Comment: Thank you. It works but it exited with code=null. And file doesnt encrypted completedly.

Comment: So, if this doesn't fully work, why have you accepted my answer?

Comment: Because It worked when I ran my script in terminal instead of VSCode script-runner .

Comment: createCipher as since been deprecated can you update your answer for the new function createDecipheriv?

Comment: @Wanjia Since this is only a niche answer I don't have the time to write and test proper code for this. I added a textual description for that. If you like, you can provide your own answer.